# Counting the number of paths through a grid graph traversing all vertices exactly once

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

So I asked a question on stack overflow and they suggested I migrate over here. I'm writing a program to solve the following problem:

> Given a grid of x by y dimensions, calculate the number of paths through it that start in one corner (let's say top right) and end in another (bottom right) and pass through every vertex exactly once

I've just been brute forcing it but it gets slow quickly and people on StackOverflow said I didn't even need to bother with traversal, and that this was just a math problem. Does anyone have any insight into how I could solve it this way?

Comment: I think it would be useful to state of parity checking case in question.

Comment: Your title seems to imply that in the body you're using the term "route" to denote a path that contains each vertex at most once? I hadn't come across that usage before.

Comment: @joriki Not sure what the proper term is, but I edited it to "path."

Comment: Now I'm confused. With that change, the title and body seem to contradict each other. In the title you want all vertices "only once" (presumably that's intended to mean "exactly once"?), and in the body you're looking for *all* paths (of which there are of course infinitely many)?

Comment: Now the body and title are in agreement, but if you mean "exactly once", that would be the preferable expression, since "only once" can also be understood as "at most once".

Comment: No, you introduced a new unexplained discrepancy between the title and the body.

Comment: Augh, nitpicking! It's clear we want the number of Hamiltonian paths.

Comment: @Lopsy: One person's nitpicking is another person's precision. I think questions should be written as carefully as possible; there's enough potential for misunderstanding as it is.

Answer (score 1):

There's the paper "[The number of Hamiltonian paths in a rectangular grid](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9500330Y)", that gives generating functions for $m \times n$ grids with $m \leq 5$. It seems like a difficult problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an 'educational' video that tries to answer a similar question:

http://youtu.be/Q4gTV4r0zRs

Also, I think this is an excellent computer science question (ie math is not ready for such hard problems, lol).

[Here](http://www.quora.com/challenges#datacenter_cooling) is your question being used as a programming challenge.  My guess is a good computer science answer involves a (depth-first) brute-force search with clever pruning along the way.