# Count all possible paths on a grid while traversing to any surrounding tiles at least zero or one time(s)

Tags: combinatorics, path-connected

This is a bit difficult to explain as I'm not a mathematician and don't know the correct terms, but I'll try my best. Any tips on improvement are welcome.

I did find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274856/counting-the-number-of-paths-through-a-grid-graph-traversing-all-vertices-exactl) but the requirements are different and it traverses the vertexes instead of the tiles.

I have a grid where I can travel from any tile to adjacent tiles, but a maximum of only one time and I want to know how many possible paths there are on the grid with a minimum length of one and a maximum length of the number of tiles.

So here are the rules listed:

- The grid is a rectangle (let's assume a 5x5 grid for this post)
- You can start at any tile in the grid
- You can travel to any surrounding tiles horizontally, vertically or diagonally with a maximum distance of 1
- No tile can be used more than once in the same path

I tried to calculate the amount of paths by the following:

- Number of tiles = `5 x 5 = 25`
- Number of maximum travel possibilities = `8`
- Number of minimum travel possibilities = `1`
- Number of options decreases with each step, but each step is a new path as well `N - 1`
- $$(25 - 1) ^ {(8 - 1 - 1)} = 191102976$$

However, I have no clue how to verify if I'm correct (I'm probably very wrong) here. In an attempt to approach it deterministically I started writing a program in C# to count it, but it has been a while and my pc's memory is getting full and the counter is at 163 million and still counting. (EDIT: My PC ran out of memory at 2533725588 paths and needed to process at least 117 million more).

What is the correct approach to calculate the number of paths here?

Here are a few grid examples:

[image: Grid examples]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk

Comment: @RobPratt From the wikipage "There is currently no known formula"... Great! :D That explains something. Thanks for the sources, looks like a duplicate indeed. Thanks for finding it!